# unable to get params from middleware into route

Tags: node.js, express

`app.js`

```
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
app.use('/admin/customer/:customerId', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('middleware id=', req.params.customerId);
    next();
}, adminRoutes);
```

and here is `routes/admin.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


router.post('/user', (req, res) => {
    console.log('route id=', req.params.customerId);
    res.json(req.params);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am getting following output

```
middleware id= 1
route id= undefined
```

while expected output is

```
middleware id= 1
route id= 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Router` `options` property `mergeParams` if you want to access `params` from the parent router.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router({mergeParams:true});


router.post('/user', (req, res) => {
    console.log('route id=', req.params.customerId);
    res.json(req.params);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: working as expected. I was missing `mergeParams:true`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

You can directly call your route without using another callback and it should work

`app.js`

```
const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
app.use('/admin/customer/:customerId',adminRoutes);
```

If it does't work then you will have to set the params in **request object** before using your routes